# Click event fails on italic text within element

Tags: jquery

I have a generated list attached to an element, `searchresults`. Clicking on a member of the list returns the associated ID but not if the area clicked is within italic tags.

This is what the generated list looks like:

```
<div id="searchresults">;
  <p id="oppnum248">Some text here (<i>And more here</i>)</p>
  <p id="oppnum786">Some other text here (<i>And here</i>)</p>
  ...
</div>
```

and this is a snippet of the jQuery code:

```
$('#searchresults').on('click', '[id^=oppnum]', function(event) {
  var oppID = event.target.id.slice(6);
  ...
});
```

Clicking on anything in italics fires the handler but the `oppID` is an empty string. On removing the italic tags the handler returns the ID on the whole text.

An online search doesn't turn up anything relevant. How should I amend my code?

```js
$('#searchresults').on('click', '[id^=oppnum]', function(event) {
      var oppID = event.target.id.slice(6);
      alert(oppID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchresults">;
      <p id="oppnum248">Some text here (And more here)</p>
      <p id="oppnum786">Some other text here (<i>And here</i>)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added a snipped, one element with italic other without to show the difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because `event.target` will be the element which was clicked; in this case either the `i` or the `p`. If it was the former then it doesn't have the `id` attribute, so returns an empty string.

To fix this use the `this` keyword within the event handler, as it will always refer to the element which the event handler is bound to, even if a child element actually raised the event. Try this:

```js
$('#searchresults').on('click', '[id^=oppnum]', function() {
  var oppID = this.id.slice(6);
  console.log(oppID);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchresults">
  <p id="oppnum248">Some text here (<i>And more here</i>)</p>
  <p id="oppnum786">Some other text here (<i>And here</i>)</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! A useful lesson in the differences between the two ways of getting an ID.